# (Too) complex configuration management (Java properties)

Tags: java, spring, properties, properties-file, configuration-management

I'm working at a company having a (too) complex configuration management process:

- In each module there is an application.properties file. There are properties for the developers like: `database.host = localhost`
- Properties which change in other environments are maintained in an application.properties file in an override-properties folder (for each module) like: `database.host=@dbhost@`
- There is a default-deployment.properties file with default values for other environments like: database.HOST=noValueConfigured.DB_HOST
- A postconfigure.properties file with `DATABASE_ HOST=@configure.DB_HOST@`

Those files are only needed if a property value depends on the environments (is different for development, testing, live).

- Finally there is a Excel document with a sheet for every environment and a row like: `configure.DB_HOST` - `a comment ...` - `127.0.0.1` (just as example). The Excel is responsible for generating the correct property files for the rpm packages.

This process is not only complex but also error prone.
How could it be simplified/improved?

The approach should be compatbiel with Spring DI.

Answer (score 4):

I would start with a master configuration file and generate the properties files to start with.

Ultimately you could have a set of proprties files which can be deployed in all environments e.g.

```
database.host = localhost
database.host.prod = proddb1
database.host.uat = uatdb1
```

i.e. use the environment/host/region/service at the end as a search path.  This has the advantage that you can see the variations between environments.

You can implement this collect like this

```
public class SearchProperties extends Properties {
    private final List<String> searchList;

    public SearchProperties(List<String> searchList) {
        this.searchList = searchList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        for (String s : searchList) {
            String property = super.getProperty(key + "." + s);
            if (property != null)
                return property;
        }
        return super.getProperty(key);
    }
```

You might construct this like

```
Properties prop = new SearchProperties(Arrays.asList(serverName, environment));
```

This way, if there is a match for that server, it will override, the environment which will overidden the default.

In Java 8 you can do

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
    return searchList.stream()
            .map(s -> key + "." + s)
            .map(super::getProperty)
            .filter(s -> s != null)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(()-> super.getProperty(key));
}
```

Comment: If the property values don't depend on the environment (meaning they're the same on dev, test and live), then they're just entered in the application.properties file and nowhere else. Only if they depend in the environment, they have to be specified in all those files.

Comment: @mosquito87 or you could do as I suggest and put them all in the same file so you can see how each application varies between environments and have only one file.

Comment: Okay, this is one idea, I will suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @mosquito87 I have added the code for this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. We're using Spring for DI. Is this strategy compatible with Spring?

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one file, even if it has a lot of properties. Also, there should be only one property for each functionality, like database.host, not database.host and database_host, or anything similar.

You need to create hierarchy for such and for every property in order to know which one will be user. For example, if there is some head global value for database.host, it should be used for that property. If not, check next level in hierarchy, like specific environments (like production value). If such does not exist, check next level, like local or test level. And for bottom level, have a default value. In such way, you have two dimension of consuming properties and as such, decreases chances for error dramatically.

In one company I used to work, we had automated deployer which would handle such level setup, we would just set variable on its web site for level we wanted and it would go from top to bottom and set them. We never had problems with such setup and we would have more then 50 variables in app.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

If not to take into consideration all the redesign methods mentioned in the previous comments, you can wrap all the complexity into [Tomtit](https://github.com/melezhik/tomtit) task manager which is good with these types if tasks.

Just create properties files [templates](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/dsl.md#templates) and populate them using [environments](https://github.com/melezhik/Tomtit/blob/master/README.md#environments)